# Data Annotations Customizada para validação

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

Quero criar uma Data Annotation para poder verificar em TODAS as paginas da minha aplicação se o usuário que está se logando, já tem 1 `Condomínio` cadastrado, caso não exista condomínio cadastrado ele redireciona para a tela de cadastro de condomínio.

oque tenho no momento é isso:

```
protected async Task<ValidationResult> IsValidAsync(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(user);

    List<ApplicationCondominium> result = await _condominiumManager.GetCondominiumAsync(userId.Id);

    if (result.Count() == 0)
    {
        return ValidationResult.
    }
    else
    {
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
 }
```

Conseguiriam me ajudar, pois preciso dessa validação em todas as paginas de minha aplicação.

Comment: é melhor criar um `filter` ou `middlwerare` se for na versão core.

Comment: `Poderia` explicar um pouco melhor amigo ? sim estou usando `core 2.1`

Comment: [Middleware ASP.NET Core 2.1](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente você precisa criar uma [Middleware](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/mt707525.aspx), que ao verificar o seu código se existe ou não um condominio faz o redirecionamento. *Exemplo*:

Crie uma classe:

```
public class RedirectNoApartment
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly bool status = true;
    private readonly string path = "/home/about";

    public RedirectNoApartment(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        status = ; // aqui você adiciona o código de verificação retornando true ou false
        if (!status && httpContext.Request.Path != path)
        {
            httpContext.Response.Redirect(path);                
        } 
        else
            await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Dentro dessa classe tem um `bool status` que é uma variável pra você pesquisar no seu banco e trazer se existe ou não condomínio para um determinado usuário e também um `string path` que o seu redirecionamento padrão para carregar a pagina de cadastro do condomínio.

Agora entre no arquivo `startup.cs` abaixo da conexão de configuração com o banco de dados adicione essa linha

```
app.UseMiddleware<RedirectNoApartment>();
```

pronto todas as vezes ele vai checar se o usuário tem ou não condomínio cadastrado

- [ASP.NET - Use Middleware Personalizado para Detectar e Corrigir 404s em Aplicativos do ASP.NET Core](http://www.codenutz.com/https-redirect-asp-net-core-using-owin-middleware/)
- [Middleware do ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Esse código pode ser melhor elaborado e adequado a suas necessidades, isso é um exemplo ser ver a sua realidade.

Comment: tentei fazer isso, mas aparentemente não está funcionando para mim pois estou recebendo o seguinte erro `InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[KonBase.Models.ApplicationUsers]' from root provider.`

Comment: Você não está conseguindo resolver um injeção então pode ser tanta coisa, qual é o seu código! @Matheus

Comment: fiz essa pergunta para resolver esse problema, `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/372861/erro-ao-usar-middleware`, coloquei todo o código lá

Comment: @Matheus eu acho que ele não vai conseguir resolver assim, inclusive se tiver usuário autenticado ele já te dá essa informação no Request, olha o código: `var id = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;` e outra coisa essa resposta é a solução primária do seu problema

Comment: Testei essa solução que me passou, mas ele não encontra o HttpContext

Comment: @Matheus é httpContext.User igual está no método invoke!, mas, na outra resposta já foi informado como fazer