# Erro ao usar Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

Estou tentando utilizar Middleware, para que toda vez que um usuário logar no sistema ele fique sendo redirecionado para tela de cadastro de condomínio, ele não pode utilizar o sistema enquanto não cadastrar ao menos 1 condomínio.

Mas estou recebendo os seguintes erros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código de meu Middleware ~/Custom/Middleware/RedirectNoCondominium.cs

```
public class RedirectNoCondominium
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUsers> _userManager;
    private readonly ICondominiumService _condominiumManager;
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly string path = "~/Condominium/Add";

    public RedirectNoCondominium(
        RequestDelegate next, 
        UserManager<ApplicationUsers> userManager,
        ICondominiumService condominiumManager)
    {
        _condominiumManager = condominiumManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _next = next;
    }

    public ClaimsPrincipal User { get; private set; }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

        List<ApplicationCondominium> result = await _condominiumManager.GetCondominiumAsync(user.Id);

        if (result.Count() == 0 && httpContext.Request.Path != path)
        {
            httpContext.Response.Redirect(path);
        }
        else
            await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

E aqui no meu startup.cs faço a chamada dele.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<RedirectNoCondominium>(); <-- aqui

        app.UseForwardedHeaders();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.IsHttps || context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"] == Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
            {
                await next();
            }
            else
            {
                string queryString = context.Request.QueryString.HasValue ? context.Request.QueryString.Value : string.Empty;
                var https = "https://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.Path + queryString;
                context.Response.Redirect(https);
            }
        });


        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseNToastNotify();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Matheus na minha resposta quais foram os seus problemas encontrados? Por acaso você utilizou `httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(UserManager<ApplicationUsers>))` que também resolve?. Por favor não abra várias perguntas da mesma duvida vamos tentar solucionar seu problema pela duvida inicial que é assim que faz, talvez tenhamos que mudar alguma coisa então comunique ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução é injetar no método `invoke`

```
public class RedirectNoCondominium
{    
    private readonly ICondominiumService _condominiumManager;
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly string path = "~/Condominium/Add";

    public RedirectNoCondominium(
        RequestDelegate next,         
        ICondominiumService condominiumManager)
    {
        _condominiumManager = condominiumManager;        
        _next = next;
    }

    public ClaimsPrincipal User { get; private set; }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext,
                             UserManager<ApplicationUsers> userManager)
    {
        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

        List<ApplicationCondominium> result = 
                await _condominiumManager.GetCondominiumAsync(user.Id);

        if (result.Count() == 0 && httpContext.Request.Path != path)
        {
            httpContext.Response.Redirect(path);
        }
        else
            await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

---

Observação é esse o código mesmo, mas, vai depender de como você fez no `Startup.cs`, exemplo:

Tem que estar configurado no método do `Startup.cs` no método `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

no método Configure depois do `app.UseAuthentication();`, exemplo:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMiddleware<RedirectNoCondominium>();
```

No método do `middlweare` assim:

```
public class RedirectNoCondominium
{        
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly string path = "/Condominium/Add";

    public RedirectNoCondominium(RequestDelegate next)
    {            
        _next = next;
    }


    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, 
                             UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            IdentityUser user = 
                await userManager.GetUserAsync(httpContext.User);
            var id = user.Id; // Id do usuário
            //trabalhe pra frente o seu código ...
            if (user != null)
            {
                if (httpContext.Request.Path.Value != path)
                {
                    httpContext.Response.Redirect(path);
                }
                else
                {
                    await _next(httpContext);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await _next(httpContext);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
}
```

- [How to do DI in asp.net core middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52204074/6797930)
- [Custom middleware with dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://blog.dudak.me/2014/custom-middleware-with-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: @Virgio Novic, com sua resposta consegui resolver o erro, mas quando mantenho o `app.UseMiddleware<RedirectNoCondominium>();` no meu arquivo `startup.cs` ele me da o erro `Esta página não está funcionando localhost não consegue atender a esta solicitação no momento.- HTTP ERROR 500`, mas quando comento `app.UseMiddleware<RedirectNoCondominium>();` no meu arquivo `startup.cs` funciona certinho

Comment: Você precisa debugar o código cara! @Matheus para ver aonde está dando o erro no servidor!, talvez possa ser sua classe, ou também a injeção não está funcionando.

Comment: Outro teste que se pode fazer: `httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(UserManager<ApplicationUsers>))`; eu não tenho como testar é com você isso @Matheus