# Ficar redirecionando o usuário até ele completar uma tarefa especifica

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-core

Estou desenvolvimento uma aplicação para gerir um condomínio.

Oque eu preciso é que após o usuário logar ele seja redirecionado para tela de cadastro de condomínio `(caso ele não tenha nenhum condomínio cadastrado ainda)` independente de que pagina ele tente acessar.

Tentei utilizar `Middleware`, mas não funcionou para mim.

Fui indicado a utilizar `Filters` mas ainda não consegui implementar.

Conseguiriam me auxiliar ?

```
public class RedirectNoCondominium
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly string path = "~/Condominium/Add";

    public RedirectNoCondominium(
        RequestDelegate next,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _next = next;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    [Authorize]
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ICondominiumService _condominiumManager)
    {
        if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            List<ApplicationCondominium> result = await _condominiumManager.GetCondominiumAsync();

            if (result.Count() == 0 && httpContext.Request.Path != path)
            {
                httpContext.Response.Redirect(path);
            }
            else
            {
                await _next(httpContext);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: E onde você está implementando esse "filter"?

Comment: Estou tentado utilizar ele em todos os controllerà, consequentemente estou utilizando por injeção de dependência no arquivo `startup,`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro ao usar Middleware](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/372861/erro-ao-usar-middleware)